# Convert a PDE to an ODE

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Assume we have two functions ($x$ and $y$ are independent):

$$f(x,y)$$ and $$f_{x}(y)$$

The second function derives from the first one, it just fixes $x$ and only depend on y.

In this case, do we have the following equation:

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} = \frac{df_{x}(y)}{dy}$$

Convert a partial derivative to an ordinary derivative?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the definition of $f_x(y)$.  Is it the function $y \mapsto f(x,y)$?

Comment: @Glitch I think $f_{x}(y)$ is the same function $f(x,y)$, just we assume f conditioned on y, i.e. x is a constant in $f_{x}(y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed $x$ you define $f_x(y) = f(x,y)$, so in fact the *definition* of the partial derivative is 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x,y+h) -f(x,y)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f_x(y+h) - f_x(y)}{h} = \frac{d f_x}{dy}(y). 
$$
So, yes, the partial derivative of $f$ in the $y$ direction is the total derivative of $f_x$.